# How do I build a deck?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers

While playing around in "Magic The Gathering" via Steam I was wondering about how one builds his deck...

- Buying "online" cards?
- Obtaining more cards as bonus for completing the campaigns?
- Where do rare cards come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You receive new cards at every
  challenge you win against computer or
  other players until you finish the
  collection.
- You cannot buy cards online or
  boosters.
- There are **expansions** to buy that
  allow to increase your  collection of
  cards. At the moment there is only
  one available on Steam. If you have
  pre-ordered the game, is already
  included in your installation.
- Another expansion should be available
  probably within some months.

Answer (score 6):

Unlike the old [microprose mtg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic:_The_Gathering_video_games#Magic:_The_Gathering_.28Microprose.29), dotp does not allow you to build a deck from scratch, or even remove any of the cards a deck starts with.

This game seems to be intended for people who have no experience in how to put together a deck, then teach them the game, and then give the offer of free paper cards - think of it as interactive advertising for paper magic.

Comment: Are there games for someone who just wants to play some MTG and build decks and such?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this is for the correct game, but...

In Magic the Gathering: Duels of the Planeswalkers, you get a new card for each battle you win. You can't change any other cards, but you can remove any of these earned cards from your deck via the deck editor.

Answer (score 2):

You receive 1 new cards for every match you win against the computer or other players until you finish that deck. (you will need to play with each deck to unlock everything.)

Expansions include additional decks, with addiotional cards to unlock. There is currently 1 expansion (included in the preorder), and more will follow.

No boosters or seperate cards can be bought, however, you can buy an unlock pack for each deck that will unlock all locked cards in that deck. (time vs. money trade-off)

You can't change the cards in the basic deck, however you can add/remove any of the additional unlocked cards from your deck via the deck editor. (they're added by default)

The final set of cards (after you've unlocked everything) is the same for everyone.

You can buy an upgrade to change your Uncommons and Rares into the Foil versions. (I consider this a bad tactic for online play, as it makes the uncommons/rares much more noticable.)